# How to mock services with Retrofit 2.0 and the new MockRetrofit class?

Tags: java, rx-java, retrofit2

Using Retrofit 1 we used to mock web services and simulate network latency as following:

```
MockRestAdapter mockRestAdapter = MockRestAdapter.from(restAdapter);
return mockRestAdapter.create(MyService.class, new MyServiceMock());
```

Where `MyService` is the service Interface (returning responses as Rx Observables), and `MyServiceMock` is a class that implements this interface.

In Retrofit 2.0.0-beta3 there is a brand new mocking system (see: https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/1343) that is not yet documented.
When trying to to something similar I get:

```
MockRetrofit mockRetrofit = new MockRetrofit.Builder(retrofit).build();
BehaviorDelegate<AuthService> delegate = mockRetrofit.create(MyService.class);
```

How do I forward calls to `MyServiceMock`?

Comment: Just as an aside, you can use MockWebServer and MockResponse to simulate mocking web services as well.

Comment: I think you could benefit from using Mockery. Take a look ;) https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/Mockery

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Suppose the interface definition is as below:

```
public interface MyService {
    @GET("/name")
    rx.Observable<String> name();
}
```

Calls will be forwarded to `MyServiceMock` using `BehaviorDelegate`. The `BehaviorDelegate` applies `NetworkBehavior` to the responses created by the mock. Note that the mock implementation below takes the `BehaviorDelegate` as a constructor argument and uses it to return the response.

```
public class MyServiceMock implements MyService {
    private final BehaviorDelegate<MyService> delegate;

    public MyServiceMock(BehaviorDelegate<MyService> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Observable<String> name() {
        return delegate.returningResponse("test").name();
    }
}
```

A sample of a test using the mock service is as shown below:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    private final NetworkBehavior behavior = NetworkBehavior.create();
    private final rx.observers.TestSubscriber<String> testSubscriber = TestSubscriber.create();
    private MyService mockService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://example.com").build();

        MockRetrofit mockRetrofit = new MockRetrofit.Builder(retrofit)
                .networkBehavior(behavior).build();

        final BehaviorDelegate<MyService> delegate = mockRetrofit.create(MyService.class);

        mockService = new MyServiceMock(delegate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccessResponse() throws Exception {
        givenNetworkFailurePercentIs(0);

        mockService.name().subscribe(testSubscriber);

        testSubscriber.assertValue("test");
        testSubscriber.assertCompleted();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFailureResponse() throws Exception {
        givenNetworkFailurePercentIs(100);

        mockService.name().subscribe(testSubscriber);

        testSubscriber.assertNoValues();
        testSubscriber.assertError(IOException.class);
    }

    private void givenNetworkFailurePercentIs(int failurePercent) {
        behavior.setDelay(0, MILLISECONDS);
        behavior.setVariancePercent(0);
        behavior.setFailurePercent(failurePercent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand I will have to rewrite all my mocks to add the the following boilerplate `delegate.returning(myMockedValue).myMethod();`. I'm not sure this is an improvement compared to Retrofit 1.

Comment: Is there a reason to ever write `delegate.returning(Calls.response(something))` if you can call `delegate.returningResponse(something))`, which does the "Calls.response()" part for you?

Comment: @Singed - You are right. There is no reason to write the long form in this case. `returningResponse` can be used. However where this can be useful is when you want to send failed responses from your mock. Example `delegate.returning(Calls.failure(new IOException("some error")))`.

Comment: I believe BehaviorDelegate uses reflection for its interface.  Isn't it a bit convoluted?  I am wondering if there is a more straightforward/simpler way to test web services.

Comment: Cannot resolve subscribe method. Where did that came from?

Comment: @LanceContreras - I believe you are asking about the subscribe() method call on name(). As name() is RxJava Observable, I am calling subscribe() method on it.

Comment: @PraveerGupta subscribe() requires no parameters. I also have the same problem as Lance Conteras

Comment: If you're using RxJava 2, I'm not sure but you *might* need to use a TestObserver instead of a TestSubscriber depending on your situation

Comment: This works fine for me when the service is returning an Observable<String> but I can't get it to work at all if I'm returning Observable<MyClass>. Any tips?