# Mocking Result<MyResponse> in Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, rx-java, retrofit2

I've followed the response in [How to mock services with Retrofit 2.0 and the new MockRetrofit class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740665/how-to-mock-services-with-retrofit-2-0-and-the-new-mockretrofit-class)

So now my question is how do I mock a [Result](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/Result.java) Eg.  `Observable<Result<String>>`

PS. In reality the `String` would be an actual POJO with a complex structure.

Comment: You can use OkHttp Mock Server and no need to mock this call. Please check https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver