# Retrofit 2 mock best practice

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, retrofit2

I am very new to testing and TDD and I decided to use use Retrofit2-Mock for my api mocking needs.
The documentation on Mock Retrofit2 is virtually non existent and the only how-to resources that I found is this [article](https://riggaroo.co.za/retrofit-2-mocking-http-responses/) from 2015 and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34745006/6432826) from 2016.

In these a BehaviorDelegate class is used which does not implement the mocked api Interface and needs to be wrapped.

Is there a more elegant way to obtain the mock api service?

Or am I missing the whole point and the Retrofit2-Mock tool is not considered to be in the "best practice stack"?
Specially since there are so few articles about it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use Mockito like this

1. Import Retrofit Mock

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
       <artifactId>retrofit-mock</artifactId>
       <version>${version.retrofit}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create and use the mock

   ```
   import retrofit2.mock.Calls;
   import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
   import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

   ...

   Api api = mock(Api.class); // Mockito mock

   ...

   when(api.doSomething(param)).thenReturn(Calls.response(response));
   ```

Retrofit Mock is used only to generate the response.

Answer (score 9):

[This issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1413) on [Retrofit's Github repo](https://github.com/square/retrofit) is asking about the non-existent documentation you were asking about (it is still open while writing this answer).

Well, you have 2 options (both are in [the article](https://riggaroo.dev/retrofit-2-mocking-http-responses/) you already mentioned), and it depends on how you want to define your **Givens/Inputs**:

### Option 1: ([Okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)'s [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver))

If you usually start your TDD by dealing with your **backend's json** response (using something like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)), & you would feel **more confident** if you used that returned json directly as the input for your tests, then use `MockWebServer`, where you would copy/paste the json you already have & start developing your tests from there.

### Option 2: ([Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)'s own [Mock Web Server](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock))

If you prefer defining your givens/inputs using **objects** for the **models** you already use in your code, which would make your tests more **readable & controllable**, then use Retrofit's mock web server just like how it is used in this [official sample](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleMockService.java) [mentioned](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1413#issuecomment-168905741) by [@JakeWharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton)

---

Both options are developed/maintained by the same awesome people of [Square](https://square.github.io/), so it is really about how you want to define your givens/inputs.

Comment: I completely forgot about this one. I'd actually use wiremock now.

Answer (score 0):

Well I thing this article could be useful in this case.

The whole idea is based on build variant you can switch between mock up server on real one.

**Annotation**, **Call Adapter** and **Interception**

This is how annotation will look like:

```
    @Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MOCKUP(vararg val value: String)
```

use this annotation in APIs before or after @GET @POST ...etc

For the full example [here](https://musab-on.medium.com/retrofit-2-mock-up-with-call-adapter-1da4b06bbb1b)