# How to mock a retrofit2 error response with Mockito thenReturn?

Tags: java, http, mockito, retrofit2, response

I have this code that I want to test:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getMaps (Query query) throws CustomException {
   Response<MapsResponse> response = mapsApi.get(); // this is a retrofit2 response
   if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
      handle(response); // throws CustomException
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

So I mocked it with mockito, but when I try to do:

```
retrofit2.Response<MapsResponse> response = retrofit2.Response.error(500, ResponseBody.create(null, content))
when(mapsApi.get()).thenReturn(response);
```

It says it cannot resolve method 'thenReturn...'

Does anyone know how can I mock an error response (error HTTP code) that will trigger my exception? Thanks!

Comment: Check your imports. Seems like you've imported the wrong `when`.

Comment: Can someone please post a working example? (Mocking a retrofit2 response) I think I'll manage to fix it from there.

Answer (score 0):

> I usually use Mockito like this
>
> Import Retrofit Mock
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
>     <artifactId>retrofit-mock</artifactId>
>     <version>${version.retrofit}</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Create and use the mock
>
> ```
> import retrofit2.mock.Calls;
> import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
> import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
>
> ...
>
> Api api = mock(Api.class); // Mockito mock
>
> ...
>
> when(api.doSomething(param)).thenReturn(Calls.response(response));
> ```
>
> Retrofit Mock is used only to generate the response.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743963/10316073), I hope this helps you